# Cannot resolve DNS after reconnecting router

Tags: networking, router, dns, wireless-router

So, whenever I do major desk cleaning I disconnect my router and all the cables and clean the desk. The weird thing is everytime I do this, after connecting it back again I always get cannot resolve DNS on my computer. And it only occurs on computers connected directly via cable. The wifi works fine. I tried flushing dns, using windows 10 network reconnecting network adapter, problems resolver, disconnecting and connecting everything again. The only thing that helps is setting DNS directly to 208.67.222.222 and 208.67.220.220. My question is why without changing any settings I always get this error and how can I prevent it in the future?

Also when I disconnect the router for a short period of time, 1-2 minutes, the problem doesn't occur. It only happens when I clean the desk, so when it's disconnected for about 15 minutes.

My router model is D-LINK DIR-655 and it's connected to another router D-Link Dir 300 which is connected straight to the internet cable.

Comment: I assume you have tried to disable then enable your network adaptor?

Comment: Yes, many times.

Comment: Have you tried to configure the router's DNS providers to OpenDNS instead of configuring the client's providers to be what the router says they should be?

Comment: No, I haven't. I'll try that.

Comment: I should clarify.  By changing the router's DNS provider to OpenDNS, instead of what they are currently, when you unplug your router for 15 minutes this problem shouldn't surface.  Your solution, indicates your problem is a DNS problem, caused for whatever reason by unplugging your router's power.  Your clients DNS are already configured to what your router's providers, your attempting to verify, if assigning a different provider will avoid having to configure each client's DNS providers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix my problem. I'm kinda ashamed, because the solution was simply just to update my network card drivers. I guess I'm so used to automatic updates that I just completely forgot that I can just go to device manager and update my drivers myself.